# Get data from collection in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I stored geopoints to an array and now I want to output these on google maps but it wont't work. No markers are set for the new geopoints.

Need help, how can I set the markers on map for the geopoints?

firestore database:

[image]

code:

```
   mounted () {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapName'), {
      center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
      zoom: 20
    });


   fb.usersCollection.where("acctPosition", "==", true).get().then(docs => {
    docs.forEach((coord) => {
     const position = new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude,coord.longitude);
     const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position,
        map: map
       });
     })
    })
  }
```

This is the output of `console.log(coord.data())`

With this geopoints I would like to set a marker in google maps. How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
   fb.usersCollection.get().then(docs => {
    docs.forEach((coord) => {
     const lat = coord.data().acctPosition[0].lat;
     const lng = coord.data().acctPosition[0].lng;
     const position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position,
        map: map
       });
     })
    })
```

`docs.forEach()` returns a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) (which "offers the same API surface as a DocumentSnapshot"). You therefore have to call the `data()` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) to get the doc fields.

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(coord.data().latitude);` in the `forEach` loop?

Comment: Nothing, no console.log

Comment: And what if you do `docs.forEach((coord) => {console.log(coord) ...`. Just trying to verify that `fb.usersCollection.where("acctPosition", "==", true).get()` really returns something...

Comment: also no output in the console

Comment: I also get not output by a string e.g   console.log('hello'); -- no result in the console

Comment: If I cut out the .where('acctPosition', '==', true) then I get an console.log output

Comment: So it means your query is not correct. Does `acctPosition` field is of boolean type ? Or text?

Comment: It is a array and inside an Object by the 0 in the picture above

Comment: Ok! So clearly `where("acctPosition", "==", true)` is not going to work. What do you want to do with this where clause?

Comment: Do in need  .where for this

Comment: Not at all! I've updated my answer in the light of these comments, removing the where clause and detailing how to read the array.

Comment: You may be interested by reading this documentation item: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

Comment: Are you sure that you have a field acctPosition for ALL the docs in the collection??

Comment: is this required?

Comment: YES it is working now. A big thanks on you and for your patience

Comment: @Lukas You may upvote my answer if you think it has helped you. Thanks!